# Secret key that shows a different result?

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, secret-key

A bit of a noob question here.

Is it possible to have an encrypted text that would show different results depending on the secret key used?
for example:
If I use secret key A the text would decrypt to show "123" 
If I use secret key B the text would decrypt to show "456"

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Search for "deniable encryption."

Comment: Easy to prove for an OTP. Not a programming question.